Android scale image with animation off the screen then transition to other view
So I am trying to create a splash screen that take my logo and slogan and scale it right off the screen and then transition to the login etc...
My XML code is as follows:
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#1f1f1d"
    tools:context=".SplashActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/appLogo"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/applogo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App Slogan"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="30dp" />

</LinearLayout>

The Scale Animation code is:
<scale
    android:duration="800"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toYScale="3"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="3" />

Lastly, the Activity code is:
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo;

    TextView text;

    Animation zoom_in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.appLogo);

        text = findViewById(R.id.appText);

        zoom_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);

        logo.startAnimation(zoom_in);

        text.startAnimation(zoom_in);

    }

}

Can anyone provide any guidance on what i am missing?!

Try this
Update the SplashActivity code like this:
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView logo;
    TextView text;
    Animation zoom_in;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen_layout);

        logo = findViewById(R.id.appLogo);
        text = findViewById(R.id.appText);

        // Load the animation
        zoom_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.zoom_in);

        // Start animation
        logo.startAnimation(zoom_in);
        text.startAnimation(zoom_in);

        // Set animation listener to transition to login
        zoom_in.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // Can leave this empty or add sound, etc.
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // Animation has ended, start the login activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish(); // Close the splash activity
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // Can leave this empty as well
            }
        });
    }
}

Create a new fade_out.xml in res/anim:
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

Then, add this in the onAnimationEnd method before starting the login activity:
logo.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out));
text.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fade_out));

